# ASP.NET JavaScript return after button click

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, dynamic, postback

Code in aspx:

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hf0" Value="No Value" runat="server"/>
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox0" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Label ID="Label0" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
<asp:Button ID="Validate" runat="server" Text="Validate" OnClick="Validate_Click"/>
```

Code in C#:

```
protected void Validate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        // Set JavaScript
        string myFn = "function Textbox0_validate(str) {"
            + "if (str.length < 5) { return 'Invalid, at least 5 chars!';} return 'Passed';}"
            + "function validateAll() {document.getElementById('hf0').value =Textbox0_validate('"+ TextBox0.Text +"');}";
        Page.Header.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<script type='text/javascript'>" + myFn + "</script>"));
        // Start JavaScript
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "validateAll", "validateAll();", true);
        // Read results
        Label0.Text = hf0.Value;
}
```

The purpose is the function 'Textbox0_validate' is it can validate the text in 'Textbox0'. Thus, when I click the button, 'Label0' should display the result of the validation.(Passed, or Invalid....) And I want to be dynamic, that's  why I added these JavaScript from the code behind. (Also, I don't want to use RegEx)

The problem with the code is, when I click the button 'Validate', it doesn't update the value of 'hf0'. However; if I click it the second time, the result of the first time will show up. So basically, I need to click the button twice to get the validation result I want. I guess there is some problem with PostBack, please help.

Comment: what if you replace `document.getElementById('hf0')` by `document.getElementById('"+hf0.ClientID+"') `

Comment: Thanks, but still didn't work. I think the problem is even I want it to run JavaScript inside of Validate_Click, but it actually holds it after finishing Validate_Click. Thus, when updating 'hf0', the value hasn't been updated.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I kinda solve my problem.
I added `Label0.Text = hf0.Value` in `Page_Load`. Then in the JavaScript, I added `__doPostBack('','');` Thus, after the JavaScript finishes, it will postback, and the value will get updated in `Page_Load`.

Comment: BTW it sounds like you were trying to do form validation, would the CustomValidator control been sufficient? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.customvalidator(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Yes, that's very helpful. However; I'm grabbing a javascript function from Acrobat. That function will return true or the error message. I kinda need to build a custom validation way on my own. but thanks

Comment: Oh yeah no problem. I've had to intercept __doPostBack a lot over the years and re-write it. The one suggestion I would have is to fill out the eventTarget and eventArgument parameters if you want to capture the corresponding Click (?) event on the back-end.